# How do I replace duplicate numbers in an integer array?

Tags: java, arrays

My question is a very basic one. To give a bit of background, I was given an assignment to write a program that stored 100 unique (i.e no repeats)values into an array and displayed them. I thought I was on the right track earlier, but when I did a test run, all I keep getting is an "out of bounds error." Eclipse tells me it's in the method "checkDouble" but I can't seem to find what's wrong. Can anyone here help me out?

```
public class exercise2 {
/*@author Paolo
 * @param hundredVal array to store values
 * @param input random number generator from 1-100
 */
public static int[] hundredVal = new int[100];
public static int n = (int) (Math.random()*100+1);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        storeVal();
    }

    /*
     * This method is meant to take 100 random values
     * from 1-100 and store them into the array hundredVal
     */
    private static void storeVal() {
        for (int i = 0; i < hundredVal.length; i++){
            hundredVal[i] = (int) (Math.random()*100+1);
            if(!checkDouble(hundredVal)){
                printVal();
            }
        }       
    }

    //This method is meant to test if there are any repeated values
    public static boolean checkDouble (int[] hundredVal){
        for (int i = 0; i < hundredVal.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; i < hundredVal.length; j++){
                if (hundredVal[i] == hundredVal [j] && i != j){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //this just prints out the numbers on the console.
    private static void printVal(){
        for (int i =0; i < hundredVal.length; i++){
            System.out.println(hundredVal[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want anyone to solve the whole assignment for me. I just want to know what is causing the out of bounds error to occur.

Comment: embarrassingly, I don't see it yet, but I can suggest a small optimization. (OK I could suggest big ones too, as I think your overall algorithm may have issues, but in keeping with the spirit of letting you do most of the work...) In checkDouble, it's redundant to compare element 3 with 99 and also compare 99 with 3, right? So i only needs to go up to hundredVal.length -2, and j can loop from i + 1 to hundredVal.length - 1.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; i < hundredVal.length; j++)`. Your condition  uses `i` instead of `j`

Comment: I'm confused as to why you are calling checkDouble from *inside* your loop, before you've finished populating the array with random numbers, and also what your plan was if there *are* duplicates generated.

Comment: @halex for the win... that will loop forever! good eyes.

Comment: you should call checkDouble() outside of the for loop in storeVal() method

Comment: @Holy crap, I didn't even notice that one. This is what I get for working close to midnight...

Comment: @RobP The plan for if a duplicate is found is to replace it with a number that hasn't been used yet. that's the part I'm planning to do on my own, I just wanted to know what the out of bounds error was.

Answer (score 0):

```
class exercise2{
public static int[] hundredVal = new int[100];
public static int n = (int) (Math.random()*100+1);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    storeVal();
    printVal();
}

private static void storeVal() {
    for (int i = 0; i < hundredVal.length; i++){
        hundredVal[i] = (int) (Math.random()*100+1);
    }     
    if(!checkDouble(hundredVal)){
            printVal();

        }

}

public static boolean checkDouble (int[] hundredVal){
    for (int i = 0; i < hundredVal.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < hundredVal.length; j++){
            if (hundredVal[i] == hundredVal [j] && i != j){
                return true;
            }
        }
            }
    return false;
        }
private static void printVal(){
    for (int i =0; i < hundredVal.length; i++){
        System.out.println(hundredVal[i]);
        }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with appropriate java collection - in your case [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) should do the job. It's a Set (contains unique values) and it's ordered. It's almost always better to go with collections instead of arrays.